# Any known relationships among quark masses?

Tags: particle-physics

Here is some numerology:

Gen 1 Mass(d)/Mass(u) = 2 = 2 * 1

Gen 2 Mass(c)/Mass(s) = 12 = 4 * 3

Gen 3 Mass(t)/Mass(b) = 40 = 8 * 5

Does standard model make any predictions of relations?
Do any GUT or string theories make any predictions of relations?

Comment: a matter of research still see http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5909

Answer (score -1):

There are no theoretical predictions for quark masses other than numerology, such as what you have presented.